# Regular Expression Java

Tags: java, regex

Have a String given by:

_xdyjp_bn_qnp_00:00:05,94_00:00:11,41 يلجأ النظام السوري إلى استخدام ذخائر عنقودية لقمع الاحتجاجا

Wanted to separate the three parts:

1. _xdyjp_bn_qnp_
2. 00:00:05,94_00:00:11,41
3. يلجأ النظام السوري إلى استخدام ذخائر عنقودية لقمع الاحتجاجا

Thought that a reasonable approach would be to find a regular expression that could match the beginning of a number which could help me separate:

1. _xdyjp_bn_qnp
2. 00:00:05,94_00:00:11,41 يلجأ النظام السوري إلى استخدام ذخائر عنقودية لقمع الاحتجاجا

The second one can be spilt up using .split(" "). But the problem is I am not able to comp up with a regular expression that can do the above.

Any help would be great!

New to regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String line = "_xdyjp_bn_qnp_00:00:05,94_00:00:11,41 يلجأ النظام السوري إلى استخدام ذخائر عنقودية لقمع الاحتجاجا";

  String pattern = "(.*?)(\\d.*?)\\s(.*)";

  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3) );
  }
}
```

Explanation:

The rules between () concern the groups you want to capture.

- Group 1: (.*?) - everything until first occurrence of the next element
- Group 2: (\\d.*?)\\s - everything between first digit and first space
- Group 3: (.*) - everything else

Comment: Can you please explain the regex that you are using.

Comment: Sure; I added a brief explanation and changed the regex to discard the whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Well. I can come up with a solution that wont necessarily use regular expressions but that will solve out your problem.

```
String your_string = "test12345xxxx"; // Replace with your string here.
String[] parts = your_string.split(" "); // Will return two parts acording to your example.
String string3 = parts[1]; // The last part of the string.
String separate = parts[0];
String string1;
String string2;
for(int i=0;i<separate.length;i++)
{
   if(isDigit(separate.charAt(i))
   {
      string1 = separate.substring(0,i);
      string2 = separate.substring(i,separate.length);
      break;
   }
}
// Basically, once you detect a number you will split the string into two.
```

I hope this helps you out. I dont know if there is a way to split a string according to "sections" of the regular expression, it will be probably require something more manual.